# Changing color of a title RichTextBox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I was experimenting on VB.NET 2010 and I was attempting to change a color of a specific text.

I created a timer that captured the current windows title and implemented it in the RichTextBox:

```
   Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles activetitle.Tick
    If strin <> GetActiveWindowTitle() Then       
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "[---" & GetActiveWindowTitle() & "---]") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        strin = GetActiveWindowTitle()
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I tried to alter the code so that when current active title is saved in the RichTextBox, it would appear in a different colour:

```
     Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles activetitle.Tick
    If strin <> GetActiveWindowTitle() Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "[---" & GetActiveWindowTitle() & "---]" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        strin = GetActiveWindowTitle()
    End If
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("[---" & "---]") Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

I attempted many different variations and looked all over the internet for this but to no success :(

Does anyone know how I can change the colour of the current active windows title that is implemented into the RichTextBox?

I would like to remind you that I do not want the whole of the RichTextBox's colour changed but only the colour of the current active windows title :)

Thanks in advance to all comments!

Comment: You are setting the `SelectionColor` property, but seem to be forgetting to set `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` before changing the color.

Comment: So how should I change this code according to that?

Comment: Find where the text you want to color is inside the textbox and set that position to SelectionStart, and then set the length of the SelectionLength property to the length of the text you want to color, then apply the SelectionColor

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) The issue is that my richtextbox is constantly changing as it records the active window title that i go on so the position is always different. Is there another code to change the colour of the "[---" "---]" ?

Comment: I am still a bit unsure what you want to color and when you want to do it, cause from the code I see, you will only see the color change for the next active window after there was no active title. Also, RichTextBox has a method called AppendText() might be better to use that one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight word to find in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609110/highlight-word-to-find-in-vb-net)

Comment: Basically this is a program that constantly logs the active window title BUT i want it to be logged in a different color which is my main issue. Ty for replying

Comment: Then your code for colouring will do, however, I doubt that your if statement will ever be true

Comment: The issue is that this code does not work so I need a solution: here's a screenshot https://gyazo.com/346b050210448961797983a731105d4e

Comment: What I understand is that you wish to color when the activeTitle is empty, I think it's a lot easier, than checking the text of the richttextbox for the said occurence

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you are making it yourself a lot harder than you should, you can rewrite your timer logic like the following

```
 Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles activetitle.Tick
    If strin <> GetActiveWindowTitle() Then
        Dim oldColor = RichTextBox1.SelectionColor
        ' save the title first
        strin = GetActiveWindowTitle()
        ' set the cursor at the end (to be sure)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Length
        ' check if the text is empty
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( strin ) Then
            ' if yes, set the color to red
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        End If
        ' add the new text to the RichTextBox
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "[---" & strin & "---]" & Environment.NewLine)
        ' revert to the previous selectioncolor
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = oldColor
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ty for replying but it was unsuccessful :( There are other things that are added to my text box so it's not purely going to be the title copied into it. I attempted your code but this is what I got gyazo.com/e80a95f31eb08de460428b795fb40168

Comment: @EricCartman I can only see that you have now something in Red, what I presume was your intention from what I can read from your question. So I am unsure what your problem still is, can you update your question with additional info?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - the image shows that only 1 of my logged titles are red but i want ALL of them to be coloured red. But I don't want my keyboard logging to be red (I said "notepad" if you see). Overall: everything red except what I write.