# Highlighting text when searching for it in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi so I've created a search system with a button, textbox and rich text box to search for items displayed in the rich text box (which are imported from a text file) and to highlight them when found. For some reason when I click the search button, it does not highlight the word that is being searched for.

This is the code I used:

```
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click  

    Dim index As Integer  = 0

      While index < rtxtEdit.Text.LastIndexOf(txtSearch.Text)  
        rtxtEdit.Find(txtSearch.Text,index ,rtxtEdit.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)  
        rtxtEdit.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red  
        index = rtxtEdit.Text.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, index) + 1  
      End While  
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write that this way instead:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim searchFor As String = txtSearch.Text.Trim
    If searchFor <> "" Then
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Dim startAt As Integer = 0
        Do
            index = rtxtEdit.Find(searchFor, startAt, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
            If index <> -1 Then
                rtxtEdit.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red
                startAt = index + 1
            End If
        Loop While index <> -1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I think the original code gets stuck in an infinite loop once there is nothing left to find since `IndexOf` will return -1, then you add 1 to it resulting in 0 (zero).  Then that 0 will be less the the position returned by `LastIndexOf` in the while loop and it goes around again.  Since it loops forever, the screen never updates and you don't see the color changes from the previous found positions...

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609110/highlight-word-to-find-in-vb-net):

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
Dim len = searchText.Length
Dim pos = rtb.Find(searchText, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
While (pos >= 0)
    rtb.Select(pos, len)
    rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
    if pos + len  >= rtb.Text.Length Then
        Exit While
    End If
    pos = rtb.Find(searchText, pos + len, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    'Clears the existing formatting
    Dim t = rtxtEdit.Text
    rtxtEdit.Text = t

    'Incremented the loop condition by 1 so that text at the beginning gets selected as well.
    While index < rtxtEdit.Text.LastIndexOf(txtSearch.Text) + 1
        rtxtEdit.Find(txtSearch.Text, index, rtxtEdit.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        rtxtEdit.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red
        index = rtxtEdit.Text.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, index) + 1
    End While
End Sub
```